# Do not send blank fields via email+contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I implemented a service booking form using contact form 7. How can I prevent unselected fields from being sent to the customer's email? My form is as follows:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span style="padding-bottom: 2em;"></span>
        <span class="products">test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="qty-count qty-count--order">
            <span class="count-reduce">–</span>
            [text text-195 class:count-input "0"]
            <span class="count-add">+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span style="padding-bottom: 2em;"></span>
        <span class="products"> test 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="qty-count qty-count--order">
            <span class="count-reduce">–</span>
            [text text-349 class:count-input "0"]
            <span class="count-add">+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

config email:

```
test1: [text-195]

test2: [text-349]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a star(*) after input.something like this:

```
[text* text-349 class:count-input "0"]
```

Comment: No. I do not want to have to fill in the fields. I mean do not send empty values to email when no field is selected.